# Liferay - Sorting documents in Resources Browser

Tags: javascript, liferay

Is it possible to sort the documents in Liferay's Resources Browser alphabetically (desc or asc) ?

Screenshot to describe the problem:

[Liferay Resources Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN00l.png)

Comment: that's the ckeditor's resource browser. You can change it - you'll have to decide if you want to do it server- or clientside (e.g. in java or javascript)

Comment: Hi Olaf, can you tell me where i could do it serverside ? ( location/path of the source files... ) I only found where to do it in javascript. Thanks.

Comment: I already done this job, and the best solution is js client side. To change server side it needs an ext plugin

Comment: Hi, i had a look how to do it client side. My approach would be to change the frmresourcelist.html (function GetFoldersAndFilesCallBack( fckXml )) and sort the files there. Is this something which could work ?